# Creating a subset of a set iteratively using vector

Tags: c++

So I want to create a subset, run that subset through code, then create a new subset. I'm using a vector for the set and subset. So far I have 3 nested for loops but I'm having trouble figuring out the variables I need.

Here's what I want to do. set = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  the value matches the index just to simplify this example. I now want subset = {} -> {0} -> {1} -> ... -> {0,1} -> {0,2} -> ... -> {0,5} -> {0,1,2} -> ... -> {0,4,5}. I'm having trouble representing the conditions in terms of variables.

Basically I want the first for loop to increase the subset size. from 0 to set.size() (this is easy). Within that loop, I want to have an iterator corresponding to the index in the element of the subset. I have this iterator initialized to subset.size(), so that we work with the last element first, then work our way to the first element in the subset. then the 3rd for loop, I want to iterate between possible values from the set. Let's say our current subset = {0,1,2} how do I let my program know to put the value '2' inside the last element of the subset, then 1 then 0?

I'm thinking it would involve something with taking the difference from set.size()-1 and subset.size()-1? But I'm not quite sure how. so then I want to iterate through until {0,1,5} and then {0,4,5} but again I'm not sure how to tell the program to stop at 4, as opposed to 5. Again I think this is something with difference but I can't quite figure it out.

to recap:

```
for loop to iterate through subset size
    for loop to iterate through subset "working" element, starting from back
        for loop to iterate through that index of subset,
        starting from the correct corresponding set value to ending
        at the correct corresponding set value
```

such that the subset goes from {} -> {0} -> {1} ->...-> {0,1} -> {4,5} -> {1,2,3} -> ... -> {1,4,5} and I dont actually need subset = {1,2,3,4,5} but it doesn't hurt my code if I can't stop before that. Again I'm looking to represent the start and end points as variables to make the inner loops work, but I can't figure it out. Huge thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

this is approximately how I would go about it.

```
//handle null subset
for ( int size = 1; size < n; i++ ) {
    int indices[size];
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) indices[i] = i;

    while ( indices[0] <= n - size ) {
        int i;
        for ( i = 1; indices[size - i] == n - i; i-- );
        indices[i]++;
        for ( i = i + 1; i < size; i++ ) indices[i] = indices[i-1] + 1;
        //print out elems using the indices in `indices`
    }
    //done with all subsets of size `size`
}
```

The outer loop should be pretty self explanatory. Including 0 seemed like it was going to make some of the inner logic annoying so I started at subsets of size 1.

`indices` holds the indices of the elements that should be included in the current subset. It starts with the indices `0`-`size-1`.

The condition for the `while` isn't exactly obvious. The last valid subset this generates contains the last `size` elements, so if the first index is past `n - size` we've gone too far.

The inside of the while loop is just incrementing the subset. It looks for the last element that can be incremented and still give a valid subset, increments it, and then resets all of the subsequent elements to be as small as possible. Then you print it out somehow.

And that should be close to something that will do what you want. Let me know if it needs clarifications or corrections.

Answer (score 0):

A trick to enumerate all subsets is to permutate a "selection flag" array, each element of which indicates whether corresponding element in original array is selected.

following is sample code:

```
void foo(const vector<int>& a)
{
    size_t size = a.size();

    // selection flag array
    // '1' indicates selected, '0' indicates unselected
    vector<int> f(size, 0);

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        // increase the count of selected elements
        f[i - 1] = 1;

        do
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (f[i])
                {
                    printf("%d\t", a[i]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");

        } while (next_permutation(f.begin(), f.end(), [](int a, int b){ return a > b; }));
        // next_permutation tries to permutate the array
        // i.e. '1 1 0 0' -> '1 0 1 0' -> '0 1 1 0' -> ... -> '0 0 1 1'(end)
    }
}
```